# Android Studio:failed to find target google apis:8

Tags: android

I was trying to import an example from internet, which seems to be made in Eclipse.
I am using Android Studio and it gives me this error.

What do I do, after opening the SDK Manager?

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target Google Inc.:Google APIs:8 : /Users/wangel/Library/Android/sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Comment: Update your sdk downloading the api8, or change the target of your project to 22 (updating the sdk before)

Comment: Refer to Paul 's answer
But in my case, I had to launch "standalone SDK manager" to have it working

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your Android SDK Manager, which you can do from Android Studio (**Tools - Android - SDK Manager**) and install the appropriate SDK version, which in your case is **8**.

Once this is done, try importing the example again, or if already imported, do a clean and rebuild (**Build - Clean Project**.